# Check if either column is null

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to check if either of the columns App.Person1 or App.Person2 have null in them.

Here is my query:

```
select App.ID, App.Firstname, App.Lastname, App.Email, App.Person1, App.Person2 
from App 
where (App.Person1 OR App.Person2 IS NULL)
```

Problem is that it won't return any rows.

Comment: `App.Advisor1 IS NULL OR App.Advisor2 IS NULL`

Comment: Sorry edited it @Siyual

Comment: Doesn't change my response :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Person1, Person2 
FROM App 
WHERE Person1 IS NULL OR Person2 IS NULL
```